# Using Match and Against in MySQL and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, full-text-indexing, match-against

I am trying to implement a search feature into my codeIgniter project. I have a table called product_search, where I am set a fulltext index using the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE `product_search` ADD FULLTEXT (`prod_title`, `prod_desc`)
```

I then search it using the following codeIgniter code:

```
$this->db->select("prod_id");
$this->db->where("MATCH (`prod_title`, `prod_desc`) AGAINST ('{$searchStr}')");
$this->db->or_where("prod_id LIKE '%{$searchStr}%'");
$this->db->or_where("prod_sku LIKE '%{$searchStr}%'");
$this->db->or_where("prod_title LIKE '%{$searchStr}%'");
$this->db->or_where("prod_desc LIKE '%{$searchStr}%'");
    
$query = $this->db->get("product_search");
```

This, however, results in the following error:

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AGAINST ('silk') OR `prod_id` LIKE '%silk%' OR `prod_sku` LIKE '%silk%' OR `prod' at line 3
>
> SELECT `prod_id` FROM (`product_search`) WHERE `MATCH` (`prod_title`, `prod_desc`) AGAINST ('silk') OR `prod_id` LIKE '%silk%' OR `prod_sku` LIKE '%silk%' OR `prod_title` LIKE '%silk%' OR `prod_desc` LIKE '%silk%'
>
> Filename: models/products_model.php
>
> Line Number: 430

Why is it putting backticks around the MATCH?

If I remove the space inbetween MATCH and the brackets following it, then I get this error message:

> Error Number: 1191
>
> Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
>
> SELECT `prod_id` FROM (`product_search`) WHERE MATCH(`prod_title`, `prod_desc`) AGAINST ('silk') OR `prod_id` LIKE '%silk%' OR `prod_sku` LIKE '%silk%' OR `prod_title` LIKE '%silk%' OR `prod_desc` LIKE '%silk%'
>
> Filename: models/products_model.php
>
> Line Number: 430

However, I used the top command to add a fulltext index.
What is going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding IN BOOLEAN MODE to against section the statement as below:

```
SELECT `prod_id`
FROM (`product_search`)
WHERE MATCH (`prod_title`, `prod_desc`) AGAINST ('silk' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR `prod_id` LIKE '%silk%' OR `prod_sku` LIKE '%silk%'
OR `prod_title` LIKE '%silk%'
OR `prod_desc` LIKE '%silk%';
```